# Game Lag: Node count on Xcode simulator vs Node count on my iPhone 5S?

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I have some code which spawns blocks from the right to left of the screen and as soon as they exit the screen they get "removed".

When I run my game on the Xcode 5S simulator the follow exists:

```
Node Count = 156
FPS = 20 fps <---- I'm not to worry about this on the emulator since the actual iPhone is always much faster.
```

However when I run the game on my iPhone 5S, the following exists:

```
Node Count = 315
FPS = between 55 and 60 fps
```

I am noticing some lag in my game on my real iPhone 5S when the frame count drops to 55 fps....

It seems that the code I am using to spawn the blocks is spawning double the nodes. However I cannot physically see double the nodes....but the numbers add up. This is the code I use to spawn the blocks.

```
 let moveBlocks = SKAction.moveByX(-self.frame.size.width * 2, y: 0, duration: NSTimeInterval(self.frame.size.width / 40))
        let unspawnBlock = SKAction.removeFromParent()


        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([moveBlocks, unspawnBlock])


let p2 = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSize(width: blockSize, height: blockSize))
    p2.fillColor = SKColor.blackColor()
    p2.strokeColor = SKColor.blackColor()
    p2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: blockSize, height: blockSize))
    p2.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) + self.frame.size.width / 2, y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    p2.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    p2.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    p2.physicsBody?.friction = 0
    p2.alpha = 1

 p2.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.blocks
    p2.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None
    p2.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.player
    self.addChild(p2)
    p2.runAction(sequence)
```

How can i reduce the lag?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This could have some issues with zPosition as well as wrong usage of the method removeFromParent().

1) For first issue it can be some nodes that are behind your background (I think you have it)

2) Second could be for example that you add some objects to different layer but you didn't use this method with new layer but using it as self.removeFromParent.

```
thatLayer.removeFromParent()
```

Please check this two possible issues. I had same problem with my game.

Comment: I think my code is spawning double the nodes...However I cannot see these nodes. Still trying to figure out why...

Thanks though